# paper-drawer-panel defaults to narrow

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, paper-elements

Using Polymer 1.0 on Firefox 39.0 and Chrome 43.0

Polymer Starter Kit

---

I essentially have:

`<body unresolved class="fullbleed layout vertical">
  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <paper-drawer-panel id="paperDrawerPanel" narrow="true">
      <div drawer>
        Drawer
      </div>
      <div main>
        Main
      </div>
    </paper-drawer-panel>
  </template>
</body>`

This is from the Polymer Starter Kit.

I ***removed*** the `forceNarrow` attribute from the `paper-drawer-panel`, and even tried adding the attribute `narrow="false"`, but when I view the site in my browser on my laptop (15" screen), the panel is always in narrow mode. When I look at the `narrow` attribute in the console, it is set to `true`.

It is my understanding that both the drawer and the main content to appear side-by-side when the window is larger than `responsiveWidth`. So why am I not seeing this behavior?

Comment: setting narrow="false" is actually setting narrow === true. The boolean attribute are always true if they exist, no matter what value you give them. The only way to make narrow false in the html is to not include it. Otherwise to set it to false you can call document.getElementById('paperDrawerPanel').narrow = false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Polymer Starter Kit, inside `app/scripts/app.js`:

```
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
  document.querySelector('body').removeAttribute('unresolved');

  // Ensure the drawer is hidden on desktop/tablet
  var drawerPanel = document.querySelector('#paperDrawerPanel');
  drawerPanel.forceNarrow = true;
});
```

The line `drawerPanel.forceNarrow = true;` forces the drawer panel to be narrow. You can comment out the line in order to get the appropriate behavior.

I believe this was included in the starter kit to demonstrate how to get the opposite behavior of always having a collapsible drawer.

Answer (score 6):

Just add `force-narrow` NOT `forceNarrow` to your `paper-drawer-panel` and remove the javascript. Polymer javascript attributes in `camelCase` like `forceNarrow`  will be matched to `camel-case` in HTML.

Using `narrow=true` won't work as this is the state of the drawer and will effectively hide the element forever.

Comment: Good point which is not well explained in Polymer 1.0 docs. For example they should mention that the JS property forceNarrow corresponds to force-narrow html attribute